# ¿como agregar letras y numeros en codigo de C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Lo que quiero saber es como puedo generar un nuevo codigo pero con lo siguiente
-al  seleccionar el primer radiobutton se genere las dos primeras letras del codigo
-al seleccionar el segundo radio button se genere la tercera letra del codigo
-y al seleccionar el boton generar se agregen los tres ultimos numeros por secuencia
(todos esos agregarse uno por uno en un label)

ejemplo: en la foto
[image: como en la foto..ayudaa]

Comment: Hola Mina!, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, agregar lo que has realizado, más información, etc**, saludos!

Comment: no entiendo tu pregunta 

Código de que ? 
que quieres generar....?

necesitas el evento OnChange? del radio button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duda por que SQL Server???!!! xd bueno te dejo el generador de códigos que realice de acuerdo al mockup que muestras.

Primero tienes que crear un formulario como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De izquierda a derecha:

Crea un groupBox con 3 radiobuttons (el nombre del groupbox para este ejercicio no importa):

A los radiobuttons nombralos como:

rbCI y de texto ponle CI
rbAT y de texto ponle AT
rbEI y de texto ponle EI

Ahora crea otro groupBox y coloca los dos radiobuttons restantes:

A los radiobutons nombralos como:

rbD y de texto ponle D
rbN y de texto ponle N

Ahora crea un botón con nombre btnGenerar y un label con nombre lblCodigo

Ahora si al código:

Lo primero que hay que saber es que de acuerdo a lo que comentas se requiere formar una cadena donde el primer el valor del primer grupo de radiobuttons se coloque al inicio del label "lblCodigo" y el valor del segundo grupo de radiobuttons se coloque despues de este, cuando el usuario presione generar se agrega un número de secuencias con formato 000.

El código de tu formulario quedaría de la siguiente forma te lo coloco completo para que te des una idea:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    string firstCode = string.Empty;
    string secondCode = string.Empty;
    int secuenceNumber = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        rbCI.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbFirstCode_CheckedChanged);
        rbAT.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbFirstCode_CheckedChanged);
        rbEI.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbFirstCode_CheckedChanged);

        rbD.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbSecondCode_CheckedChanged);
        rbN.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbSecondCode_CheckedChanged);
    }

    private void rbFirstCode_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;

        firstCode = radioButton.Text;

        ShowbuildCode();
    }

    private void rbSecondCode_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton radioButton = sender as RadioButton;

        secondCode = radioButton.Text;

        ShowbuildCode();
    }

    private void ShowbuildCode()
    {
        lblCodigo.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", firstCode, secondCode, (secuenceNumber.Equals(0) ? string.Empty : secuenceNumber.ToString("000")));
    }

    private void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        secuenceNumber++;
        ShowbuildCode();
    }
}
```

Las variables

```
string firstCode = string.Empty;
string secondCode = string.Empty;
int secuenceNumber = 0;
```

sirven para almacenar el valor actual de los radiobuttons y el valor actual de la secuencia

En el siguiente fragmento de código se le indica a el grupo de radiobuttons 1 que tendrán asignado en su evento  CheckedChanged el evento rbFirstCode_CheckedChanged y se hace lo mismo pero esta ves con el grupo de radiobuttons 2 y asignandoles en el  ChechedChaged el event rbSecondCode_CheckedChanged

```
rbCI.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbFirstCode_CheckedChanged);
rbAT.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbFirstCode_CheckedChanged);
rbEI.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbFirstCode_CheckedChanged);

rbD.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbSecondCode_CheckedChanged);
rbN.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(rbSecondCode_CheckedChanged);
```

Ambos eventos tiene la misma funcion solo que en el primero se le asigna el valor del radiobutton del primer grupo a la variable firstCode y en el segundo se le asigna el valor del radiobutton del segundo grupo a la variable secondCode
finalmente se invoca el método que actualiza el label para mostrar el código generado:

```
 private void ShowbuildCode()
{
    lblCodigo.Text = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", firstCode, secondCode, (secuenceNumber.Equals(0) ? string.Empty : secuenceNumber.ToString("000")));
}
```

si te das cuenta en el string.Format se indica una secuencia que debe seguir la cadena donde {0} es cualquier valor del grupo 1 de radiobuttons y {1} es el valor del grupo 2 de radiobuttons y finalmente {2} seria el valor actual de la secuencia.

El evento que tiene ligado el boton btnGenerar se encarga de incrementar el valor de la secuencia y llamar al método que actualiza el valor del label:

```
private void btnGenerar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    secuenceNumber++;
    ShowbuildCode();
}
```

recuerda asignar este metodo btnGenerar_Click al botón en el formulario de eventos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí hay algunas salidas del programa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es justo lo que buscaba :D pero tambien quiero saber si para generar ese codigo tengo que utilizar parametros en sql , osea ya cuando conecte la BD a C#

Comment: Que tal Mina, no me queda claro muy bien tu pregunta, si te refieres a insertar ese código a una base de datos, por supuesto que se puede, si te refieres a que los radiobuttons del primer y segundo grupo se creen de acuerdo a lo que tienes en base de datos tambien se puede y de generar la secuencia desde BD tambien se puede, solo que requiere de otra logica, no complicada pero si adicional.

Comment: Me refiero a que ese código que genere en C# también se guarde esos cambios en una base de datos :D .. osea me gustaria que me des una idea de como hacer los parametros en sql server